# Finding the norm of a complex trigonometric function?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, normed-spaces

Given that the complex norm $|z| = 1$, how would I go about proving that $|cos(z)| \leq e$?  Just a hint would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z=e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$.

$\cos z=\frac12(e^{ie^{i\theta}}+e^{-ie^{i\theta}})=\ldots$

Comment: I follow what you've done, I'm just not sure what I should be doing with that second equality.  Substitute for `|z| = 1` and triangle inequality?

Comment: $|e^{ie^{i\theta}}|=|e^{i\cos\theta-\sin\theta}|=e^{-\sin\theta}\leq e$ and $|e^{-ie^{i\theta}}|\le e$...

Answer (score 0):

Write out $$\cos{z} = \frac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2} $$ and apply the triangle inequality.
 There will be some minor details to work out, but they should be fairly straightforward :)